# Outlook View Control

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm wanting to embed a user's outlook calender using the Outlook View Control; however, I'm having problems just displaying the calendar for that current day (not the whole week/month).

Here's my current code

```
<object classid="CLSID:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" id="ViewCtlFolder">
    <param name="Namespace" value="MAPI">
    <param name="Folder" value="Calendar">
    <param name="ViewXml" value="">
    <param name="DeferUpdate" value="0">
</object>
```

Whenever I try to add the parameter 
`<param name="View" value="Today">` 

it defaults back to the user's inbox as indicated here:
http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=70

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the view to "Day" but by default it should open on the current day if the folder is set try

```
<OBJECT classid=CLSID:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
id=ViewCtlFolder
width="100%"
height="430">
<param name="Namespace" value="MAPI">
<param name="Folder" value="Calendar">
<param name="Restriction" value="">
<param name="DeferUpdate" value="0">
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that did not solve the problem. It looks like I may just look into adding this progamatically, as the Object relies on having outlook installed on the user's computer regardless.

Comment: You might hit permission problems .. What is you code that you are using exacly ? as you do viewxml etc.

Comment: Also what versions are you running of outlook ? 2007

Comment: Ok as I thought I think you have hit a permission problem being outside outlook. if you use no view then it default to what displayling in outlook. if you embed into outlook all works fine!! Whats ultimatly are you trying to do ? diaply a today list as may be EWS or webdav can help you there ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by modifying the ViewXml.  I did this using JavaScript.

JavaScript replaces the current `<mode>` tag and sets it to `5`, which is the "Today" mode.

```
document.getElementById("ViewCtlFolder").ViewXml = document.getElementById("ViewCtlFolder").ViewXml.replace(/<mode>.*?<\/mode>/, "<mode>5</mode>")
```